# Getting improper data while perform devide operation in android

Tags: android

I am doing as below :

```
var value = 0.0
value = ((3300/1000).toDouble())
```

But getting value as 3.0 instead of 3.3

Why ?

Where am I doing mistake ? What I have to do to get the value as 3.3 ?

Comment: `3300/1000` these aren't double values

Comment: please provide solution to get values as 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are dividing integers and then converting them to a double *afterwards*, which doesn't work like you want it to.

```
3300/1000
```

these are integers, so no decimal values. 3300/1000 is just 3

```
3300.0/1000.0
```

these are doubles, so they have decimal values